# How to Inject FacesContext in Arquillian

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception, jboss-arquillian

Is it possible to inject FacesContext in Arquillian test? Or better approach is to mock it? I couldn't find any example from the last years on the web. FacesContext is null.

```
@Category(Arquillian.class)
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ControllerIT extends ArquillianDeployementsIT {

@Inject
private Controller controller;


@Test
public void shouldInitialize() {
    controller.getStatistics();
}


@ManagedBean 
@ViewScoped
public class Controller {

public void getStatistcs(
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      }

   }
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: Which container are you using to test? Are you using the servlet protocol? For Faces testing have you looked at Warp?

Comment: Hi. We are using JBOSS EAP-6.4.0. And no, because we would like to have code coverage for those tests, which is not possible for functional tests running outside of the container (testable=false)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the problem like this, maybe it helps someone.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javax.faces.application.Application;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.Flash;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public abstract class ContextMocker extends FacesContext {

private static final Release RELEASE = new Release();

private ContextMocker() {
}

public static FacesContext mockServletRequest() {
    FacesContext context = mock(FacesContext.class);
    setCurrentInstance(context);
    Mockito.doAnswer(RELEASE)
            .when(context)
            .release();
    Map<String, Object> session = new HashMap<>();
    ExternalContext ext = mock(ExternalContext.class);
    HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    when(ext.getSessionMap()).thenReturn(session);
    when(context.getExternalContext()).thenReturn(ext);
    when(ext.getRequest()).thenReturn(request);
    when(ext.isUserInRole(anyString())).thenReturn(true);
    return context;
}
private static class Release implements Answer<Void> {

    @Override
    public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        setCurrentInstance(null);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

and in the test:

```
@Category(Arquillian.class)
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class LoginControllerIT extends ArquillianWebIT {

@Inject
private LoginController loginController;

private FacesContext facesContext;

@Before
public void init() {
    facesContext = ContextMocker.mockServletRequest();
}

@After 
public void release() {
    facesContext.release();
}

 @Test...
```